# How to make numbers as type double don't appears like that(24.9999) in JFrame

Tags: java, floating-point, double, number-formatting

I am doing one program that calculates your BMI(body mass index),everything is working,but the result that appears,It's not right,because appears one number giant,like 24,99999 and I want that only appears something like 24,99.

My code is that :

```
  height = Double.parseDouble(txtHeight.getText());
                    weight =     Double.parseDouble(txtWeight.getText());           
                    bmi = height/weight;
                    bmi = weight/3.24;              


                    if(bmi < 17) {
                        lblBMI.setText("Your BMI is : " +bmi  + "," + " very underweight");
                    }
```

**Example : If I put Height like 1,80 and Weight like 45 It will appears in the result as Your BMI is 13,88888888888888888.**

**PS : All the variables are Double.**

Comment: Use `NumberFormat`, `System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(bmi));`

Comment: If I had saw that question I would never ask,sorry If you think that It's duplicate,but I think It's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the String.format() method like so:

```
double d = 7.9352;
String s = String.format("%.2f",d);
```

which will output 7.93 because the 2 in %.2f represents the number of digits that you want to include after the decimal point.

Alternatively if all you're doing is printing out the string you can use System.out.printf() like so:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",d);
```

Comment: While I'm not going to argue that this works (and works better then I expected it to), `NumberFormat` would allow you to format the value according to the current local which might be preferred.  Still +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks man,It worked,I am very happy,thanks really. PS: And the code was very sample,nothing hard to understand.